# Grep variable number before / after string from textline

Tags: text-processing

I want to grep a number from a Textline.

```
cat log.txt | grep "License term"

01/01/2024:00:30 License term is 123 days.
```

I only want to seperate the "downcounting number" from that.
Is there a way to echo a word before / after matching keyword? Like "output the string after "is"" or "output the string before "days""?

Its most likely the same, but can change in the future. (Format of the Log-entry or other words will be added)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) add your operating system so we know what tools you have and what implementations (there are many different `grep`s), ii) add an example input, including lines that match and lines that do not match, and iii) the output you want to see from that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `sed` command will find any line in `log.txt` that matches the regular expression `.*License term is \([0-9]*\) days\.$`, i.e., any line that contains the substring `License term is` , followed by an optional positive integer, followed by the substring  `days.` at the end of the line.  When such a line is found, the whole line is replaced by the integer, and the modified line is outputted, effectively extracting the number that you are asking for.

```bash
sed -n 's/.*License term is \([0-9]*\) days\.$/\1/p' log.txt
```

Another way of doing this is with `awk`.  The following uses a slightly different approach, just matching lines that contain the string `License term` and then outputting the second-to-last space-delimited word on these lines:

```bash
awk '/License term/ { print $(NF-1) }' log.txt
```

You may obviously also combine `grep` with e.g. `cut` to cut out the 5th space-delimited field from the lines containing the string `License term`:

```bash
grep -F 'License term' log.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

I'm using `grep` with its `-F` option here to signal that we are searching with a string rather than with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `grep`, you can use the `-o` and `-P` options, which mean "print only the matching part of the line" and "use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions" respectively. With PCRE, we can use `\K` which means "discard anything matched up to this point". Combining all this gives us:

```
$ grep -oP 'License term is \K\d+' log.txt 
123
```

Whether that will work consistently, of course, depends on what else you have in `log.txt`, but it will work for your example.

Answer (score 1):

With `pcre2grep` (or its predecessor `pcregrep`):

```
pcre2grep -xo1 '\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d:\d\d:\d\d License term is (\d+) days\.' < log.txt
```

Would do a conservative matching of those lines, only selecting the ones that match that pattern e`x`actly, and `o`utput the number matched by the `1`<sup>st</sup> capture group from there.

Or the same with perl (the `p` in `pcre2grep`):

```
perl -lne '
  print $1 if m{^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d:\d\d:\d\d License term is (\d+) days\.$}
  ' < log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same I would prefer awk than grep something like `awk '{ print $5 }'` or if you want also the date `awk '{ print $1" "$5 }'`

Comment: Note that space is the default output delimiter, so there's no need to explicitly concatenate a space between two fields.  Just do `print $1, $5`.  Also, you can get at the 2nd to last field with `$(NF-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.put if s/ .* "License term is " (<[0..9]>*) " days." $/$0/;'  log.txt   

#OR:

~$ raku -ne '.put if s/ .* License \s term \s is \s (<[0..9]>*) \s days \. $/$0/;'  log.txt

#OR:

~$ raku -ne '.put if s/ .* License <.ws> term <.ws> is <.ws>  (<[0..9]>*) <.ws> days \. $/$0/;'  log.txt
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if /License \s term/ { put .words[4] };'  log.txt

#OR:

~$ raku -ne 'put .words[4]  if /License \s term/;'   log.txt
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -e '$0.put for lines.match(/ "License term is "  ( \d+ ) \. $ /);'  log.txt 

#OR:

~$ raku -e '.put for lines.match(/ "License term is "  ( \d+ ) \. $ /);'  log.txt
```

These answers written in Raku are similar in many respects to the excellent `sed` and `awk` answers already posted. The first two sets of answers use the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. In the first set the `s///` form is used. In the second set Raku's `words` routine is used to split on whitespace. In the last set of answers, Raku's `lines` routine is used to find/return sub-`match`es.

Sample Input:

```
#dummy_line followed by blank line

01/01/2024:00:30 License term is 123 days.
#dummy_line
```

Sample Output:

```
123
```

*"Capture markers" as well as look-aheads / look-behinds are also available using the Raku regex engine. See first link below for details. Also, you have your choice of capturing `<[0..9]>` ASCII digits, or `\d` ASCII-plus-Unicode digits.*

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regexes
https://raku.org